# Connection don't close if I use statement.setQueryTimeout

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, datasource

I write simple test, using `SingleConnectionDataSource` from spring:

```
public void checkDataSourceHealth() throws SQLException {
    SingleConnectionDataSource ds = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/default");
    ds.setUsername("sys");
    ds.setPassword("qwerty");
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")

    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            statement.setQueryTimeout(2);
            statement.execute("SELECT SLEEP(3)"); //just for test. Will be 'SELECT 1'
        }
    } catch (MySQLTimeoutException ex) {
        //data base is BUSY
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Check dataSource health failed");
        throw e;
    } finally {
        dataSource.destroy();
    }
}
```

I just want to check that if my request is completed for more than 2 seconds, set the status to BUSY. It's work, but after this I check `show processlist;` I see live connect:
[image]

But why? I closed all after execute this query. Why connect is alive?

Comment: Becasue you're using a connection pool. A query timeout isn't fatal to the connection. It got returned to the pool.

Comment: @user207421, ok. How can I get around this? How can I physically close the connection after verification?

Comment: @user207421, And I destroyed the datasource, and the connection is still alive

Comment: @user207421, ok, I try too simple method via `DriverManager.getConnection` witout any pool. I get same effect!

Comment: I don't know MySQL but I think [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/281420/should-i-worry-about-mysql-sleep-status-process-in-processlist) should help you